# Kentico 11: Multi-culture set up but need to create URL outside of a culture

Tags: kentico

We have set up Kentico 11 using cultures (we have 10 different cultures) but also need the flexibility to create a URL that does not contain a culture folder within its structure.

Current scenario:

domain.com/en-gb/pageurl

Ideal scenario:

domain.com/pageurl

How can I do this? Do I need to set up a separate subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Page URL Path section of URLs tab in Pages application to define the URL you want even without language prefix. It will be unique per language. Here is the example:

[image: custom urls]

Comment: Thanks for the response Dmitry. This allows me to change the name of the URL without changing the page title but the culture folder remains within the URL itself. It's that part that I am looking to disguise. We have a multi culture set up within Kentico (that corresponds with different countries we operate within) but need to have 'global' landing pages i.e. with no culture folder within the URL.